# V Json Data is not getting read in Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am reading one line `json` data from Twitter in a Hive External Table. The table gets created but while reading the data, I get an error. I want to read the hashtags. I've followed the below steps:

```
hive (test)> add jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;                   
Added /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to class path
Added resource: /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Data in file:

```
hive (test)> dfs -cat abhijit_hdfs/flume2/tweets/Twitter_test.js;

"entities":{"symbols":[],"urls":[],"hashtags":[{"text":"AchieveMore","indices":[56,68]}]}
```

DDL statement

```
hive (test)> create external table tt4  
           > (entities struct<hashtags:array<struct<text:string>>>)
           > row format serde 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
           > LOCATION '/user/training/abhijit_hdfs/flume2/tweets/' ;
OK

Time taken: 0.193 seconds.
hive (test)> select * from tt4;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1cc892e; line: 1, column: 1]
Time taken: 0.384 seconds
```

Please Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Friends this issue is solved I Downloaded and saved following jar and restarted my claudera VM(Non commercial use).Thank you for your help which gave me direction to solve it.

`hive> add jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar;`

`Added /usr/lib/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar to class path`

`Added resource: /usr/lib/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

`hive> create external table t24`

> `(entities struct<hashtags:array<struct<text:string>>>)
>   row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
>   LOCATION '/user/training/abhijit_hdfs/flume4/tweets/'
>   ;
>   OK`
>   `Time taken: 1.623 seconds
>   hive> select * from t24;
>   OK
>   {"hashtags":[{"text":"AchieveMore"}]}
>   null
>   Time taken: 1.13 seconds
>   hive>`

Comment: You are still doing it the hard way. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Dudu really thank you ,I have noted your updated reply.You are doing great job by helping new learner's.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a non-Hadoop or hive related issue and rather a JSON serializer error the serde which you are pointing to internally uses org.codehaus.jackson

On trying the JSON it seems to have this error

```
 `Error: Parse error on line 1:"entities":{"symbols":[],"urls
                               ----------^
        Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'`
```

I haven't tried the whole setup but the JSON seems to be missing an { at start to be a good parsable JSON

```
{"entities":{"symbols":[],"urls":[],"hashtags":[{"text":"AchieveMore","indices":[56,68]}]}}
```

Comment: Hello Grey,thank you for your reply I implemented changes in data as mentioned by you but now I am getting following error,                                                            `Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable `                                                                      `Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
`

Answer (score 0):

It does work after adding surrounding curl brackets (`{...}`), when using the hcatalog JsonSerDe

```
create external table tt4
(
    entities    struct<hashtags:array<struct<text:string>>>
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
;
```

---

```
select * from tt4
;
```

---

```
+---------------------------------------+
|               entities                |
+---------------------------------------+
| {"hashtags":[{"text":"AchieveMore"}]} |
+---------------------------------------+
```

---

> The JsonSerDe for JSON files is available in Hive 0.12 and later.
>
> In some distributions, a reference to **hive-hcatalog-core.jar** is
>   required. ADD JAR /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/lib/hive-hcatalog-core.jar;
>
> ...
>
> The JsonSerDe was moved to Hive from HCatalog and before it was in
>   hive-contrib project. It was added to the Hive distribution by
>   HIVE-4895.
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormats&SerDe

Comment: Hi Dudu thank you for reply, which jar did you use ,I am getting error as,             
          ` hive (test)> create external table t17
           > (entities struct<hashtags:array<struct<text:string>>>)
           > row format serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
           > LOCATION '/user/training/abhijit_hdfs/flume3/tweets/'
           > ;
           FAILED: Error in metadata: Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
`